# Turn collection in firebase into array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to nodejs and there's a problem I can not solve.
I use nodejs and firebase database. In the database I have a collection that I have on "engineers", and I want move the data from the database to the array.

This is the database I have: I want to turn preferences into an array:

[image]

I want to get this array:

```
  const engineers = [
    // frontend engineers
    { html: 5, angular: 5, react: 3, css: 3 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, css: 4 },
    { html: 4, react: 5, vue: 4, css: 5 },
    { html: 3, angular: 3, react: 4, vue: 2, css: 3 },

    // backend engineers
    { nodejs: 5, python: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, redis: 3 },
    { java: 5, php: 4, ruby: 5, mongo: 3, mysql: 5 },
    { python: 5, php: 4, ruby: 3, mongo: 5, mysql: 4, oracle: 4 },
    { java: 5, csharp: 3, oracle: 5, mysql: 5, mongo: 4 },

    // mobile engineers
    { objc: 3, swift: 5, xcode: 5, crashlytics: 3, firebase: 5, reactnative: 4 },
    { java: 4, swift: 5, androidstudio: 4 },
    { objc: 5, java: 4, swift: 3, androidstudio: 4, xcode: 4, firebase: 4 },
    { objc: 3, java: 5, swift: 3, xcode: 4, apteligent: 4 },

    // devops
    { docker: 5, kubernetes: 4, aws: 4, ansible: 3, linux: 4 },
    { docker: 4, marathon: 4, aws: 4, jenkins: 5 },
    { docker: 3, marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, nagios: 3 },
    { marathon: 4, heroku: 4, bamboo: 4, jenkins: 4, linux: 3, puppet: 4, nagios: 5 }
  ];
```

This is the code I wrote down so far, but it does not work for me.

```
//enginer.js file

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.getPreferancesArray = (req,res) => {
  let engineers = {};
  db.collection(`/preferences`).get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      engineers = doc.data();
      console.log(engineers);
    }
    res.json(engineers);
  });
};

//index.js
const {
  getPreferancesArray
} = require('./enginer');

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.get('/kmeansArray', FBAuth, getPreferancesArray);

exports.api = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(app);
```

The problem is: I can not turn content from the database into an array, I do not understand what the problem I have been delaying it for several hours.
I want the enginer variable to have the array

Comment: If you are calling get on a collection then it should return a query snapshot. That snapshot contains the documents you are looking for. Try to map the documents to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
let engineers = [];

db.collection("preferences").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    console.log(`Found ${querySnapshot.size} documents.`);
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        const engineerDetails = doc.data();
        engineers.push(engineerDetails);
    });

    // Here the engineers array is fully populated
    console.log(engineers.length);
    res.json(engineers);

});
```

We first declare and empty array, then we loop over the documents in the `preferences` collection and, for each document, we push (i.e. add) the object returned by the [`data()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#data) method to the array. At the end we have an Array containing all the engineers data.

---

Note that this will return the field names with the underscore (i.e. `{ _html: 5, _angular: 5, _react: 3, _css: 3 }`) because we don't do any transformation on the object returned by `data()`. If you want to remover the `_`, it's up to you to manipulate the object returned by `data()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the array is empty, can you tell me why it does not work for me?

Comment: I have made a mistake... forgot the loop! Updated!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'm trying to run the code, it seems everything is working, but I can not see what's inside the array, it shows me that the array is empty

Comment: I’ve added a console.log in the answer to log the size of the array. What do you see in you log?

Comment: After I do res.json(engineers);
I do console.log (engineers) and I get blank arrays of array. [].
Is the array really empty? Or is it full and can I use it for calculations?

Comment: I have added another console.log. What are the outputs of the two console.log?

Comment: The first print returns: "Found 16 ducoments", the second print returns: 0

Comment: There was another mistake... sorry for that. I’ve updated the answer: you should send back the response from the then() block.